# Use values from list in order to create few new Dataframe based on existing one

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

My current DF looks like below

```
x  y  z  x  c name  status
1  2  3  2  5 Jon   Work
1  2  5  4  5 Adam  Work
9  7  3  9  5 Adam  Holiday
3  2  3  4  5 Anna  Work
1  4  6  8  5 Anna  Work
4  1  6  8  5 Kate  Off
2  1  6  1  5 Jon   Off
```

My lists with specific values looks like below:

```
name = [Jon, Adam]

status = [Off, Work]
```

I need using those lists create new dataframes for all unique elements in "status" list. So it should looks like below:

df_off:

```
x  y  z  x  c name  status
2  1  6  1  5 Jon   Off
```

there is only one values, because name Kate in not in the list name

df_Work:

```
x  y  z  x  c name  status
1  2  3  2  5 Jon   Work
1  2  5  4  5 Adam  Work
```

In second DF there is no "Anna" because she is not in list "name".

I hope it is clear. Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Regard
Tomasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part, filter your data using:

```
name = ['Jon', 'Adam']
status = ['Off', 'Work']
df[df['name'].isin(name)&df['status'].isin(status)]
```

Then use `groupby` and transform the output to dictionary:

```
conditions = df['name'].isin(name)&df['status'].isin(status)
dfs = {'df_%s' % k:v for k,v in df[conditions].groupby('status')}
```

Then access your dataframes using:

```
>>> dfs['df_Work']
   x  y  z  x.1  c  name status
0  1  2  3    2  5   Jon   Work
1  1  2  5    4  5  Adam   Work
```

You can even use multiple groups:

```
dfs = {'df_%s_%s' % k:v for k,v in df.groupby(['name', 'status'])}
dfs['df_Adam_Work']
```

If you goal is to save the subframes:

```
for groupname, df in df[conditions].groupby('status'):
    df.to_excel(f'df_{groupname}.xlsx')
```

Comment: It looks great! Thanks! And do you have mayby idea how to save this into excel with names df_work and df_off?

Comment: I am trying to use:

for i in status:
    pd.DataFrame(dfs[f'{i}']).to_excel[f'name {i}.xlsx']

but i get error TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable